# Date returns null values after submiting edit form in php

Tags: php, mysql

Date returns null values after submiting edit form in php

**`HTML CODE IS`**

```
<form  class="form-horizontal"  action="" method="post" >
    <label for="coupon_strt_date" >Start Date</label>


     <input type="text" name="coupon_strt_date" id="datepicker"  value="<?php echo $cats_rows['coupon_strt_date'];  ?>" class='datepick'>
    <label for="coupon_exp_date" class="control-label">Exp Date</label>
    <input type="text" name="coupon_exp_date"  value="<?php echo $cats_rows['coupon_exp_date'];  ?>" id="datepicker" class='datepick'>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>


    <?php
include("config.php");

$tbl_name = "coupons";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$id=$_POST['id'];
    $coupon_strt_date = $_POST['coupon_strt_date'];
    $coupon_exp_date = $_POST['coupon_exp_date'];

$sql="update $tbl_name set coupon_strt_date = STR_TO_DATE('$_POST[coupon_strt_date]', '%m/%d/%Y'), coupon_exp_date = STR_TO_DATE('$_POST[coupon_exp_date]', '%m/%d/%Y') where id='$id'";
if (!mysql_query($sql))
  {
 echo "Error Accured";
  }
  else {
 echo " Successfull";
  }
}
```

While iam saving data.. Dates are getting null value after chaning the date..add form is working fine..but edit form is dates are getting null value.. please sugguest me with correct code..

Comment: are you sure this `%m/%d/%Y` is the format in which you receive the dates? output the query before execution

Comment: What does "date returns null value" means ? You read dates from database and they are not set ? The $_POST fields are not set ? Please show the relevant code

Comment: You can't put array variable inside a string, either use the `$coupon_str_date` and escape your variables before the query to protect from SQL Injection

Comment: yes this format is %m/%d/%Y correct. But error same

Comment: what is the table schema?

Comment: @eric.itzhak Yes, you can interpolate array elements inside a string, as long as the key is a literal, as it is here.

Comment: What does `echo $sql;` show?

Comment: @Barmar Form submiting fine...date is changing.

Comment: If it's fine, why don't you want to show us?

Comment: Alryt i have added full code in my question.. please peruse

Comment: What is the output of $_POST['cupon_start_date'] and cupon exp date? Let me know this two values. This post can explain to you why return null. http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/str_to_date.php

Answer (score 0):

Hi if the date filled is getting null please send the schema of table or mention the data type  of date field. The date field is getting null because you are trying to save improper data types. 
data type date accept date in   yy-mm--dd  format and you are giving  %m/%d/%Y format due to which it is getting null. Hope it will hepl you.

Comment: what is the data type of column  "coupon_strt_date" and "coupon_exp_date"  in your coupons tables.

Comment: any upldates ? Please let me know if you know the answer

Comment: data type date accept date in   yy-mm--dd  format and you are giving  %m/%d/%Y format due to which it is getting null. Hope it will hepl you. as i mention in my answer .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338533/date-returns-00-00-0000-values-after-submiting-edit-form-in-php?noredirect=1#comment25153991_17338533 I found the solution here