# Date returns 00 00 0000 values after submiting edit form in php

Tags: php, mysql

Date returns null values after submiting edit form in php

**`HTML CODE IS`**

```
<form  class="form-horizontal"  action="" method="post" >
    <label for="coupon_strt_date" >Start Date</label>


     <input type="text" name="coupon_strt_date" id="datepicker"  value="<?php echo $cats_rows['coupon_strt_date'];  ?>" class='datepick'>
    <label for="coupon_exp_date" class="control-label">Exp Date</label>
    <input type="text" name="coupon_exp_date"  value="<?php echo $cats_rows['coupon_exp_date'];  ?>" id="datepicker" class='datepick'>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>


    <?php
include("config.php");

$tbl_name = "coupons";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$id=$_POST['id'];
    $coupon_strt_date = $_POST['coupon_strt_date'];
    $coupon_exp_date = $_POST['coupon_exp_date'];

$sql="update $tbl_name set coupon_strt_date = STR_TO_DATE('$_POST[coupon_strt_date]', '%m/%d/%Y'), coupon_exp_date = STR_TO_DATE('$_POST[coupon_exp_date]', '%m/%d/%Y') where id='$id'";
if (!mysql_query($sql))
  {
 echo "Error Accured";
  }
  else {
 echo " Successfull";
  }
}
```

While iam saving data.. Dates are getting null value after chaning the date..add form is working fine..but edit form is dates are getting null value.. please sugguest me with correct code..

Comment: What are you inputting? And why are you not sanitizing?

Comment: What's your table structure?

Comment: using date picker Format is M D Y.

Comment: Why do you post the same question several times?

Comment: you've got an EDIT link below your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $coupon_strt_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['coupon_strt_date']));
    $coupon_exp_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['coupon_exp_date']));

    $sql="update $tbl_name set coupon_strt_date = '$coupon_strt_date', coupon_exp_date = '$coupon_exp_date' where id='$id'";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dates needs to be stored in **`YYYY-MM-DD format`** in your database.